# How to access a session value from the form in symfony

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have a variable that is set to session from the action form.
I need to access the variable in the form
How can i do it?
This is the code I am going to access the variable.

```
    $this->unitCost = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('unit_cost');
    //assign variable to session value
    $value_lists = ($this->unitCost);
    //select value from foreach
    print_r($value_lists);
    foreach($value_lists as $values)
    {
        $newValue = $values['unit_cost'];
    }
```

I want to access this $newValue any where in the form

I want to use this code inside the     public function configure() { }in sFform where the widgets are defined. how Can I do it? Please help me in this.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call your form you can set it variables like this :

```
$this->form = new YourForm(null, array('Myvalue' => $newValue));
```

and get it in your form like this:

```
$newValue = $this->getOption('Myvalue');
```

Comment: Your solution is a good idea, but I will rather give the full user object instead of only one value.

Comment: I want to display the code I have posted in the sfForm where Widgets are declared. I cant use this code, I have already tried to do it. is there any method to get the value I have put in to the session inside the sfForm?